# 50% (of) cases?

Tags: prepositions

I want to write a sentence, like:

The investigation can reveal the cause in 50% (of) cases.

Google search within the .gov domain shows zero results for both ["50% cases"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&ei=fFGGW_OGOoTWsAHkoIKYAQ&q=site%3Agov%20%2250%25%20cases%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%2250%25%20cases%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...110692.111066.0.111860.3.3.0.0.0.0.110.283.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.hYTypcflKhw) and ["50% of cases."](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=bFGGW_STOY_VsAH7u5bQBQ&q=site%3Agov%20%2250%25%20cases%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%2250%25%20cases%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1428.7260.0.7910.21.20.0.0.0.0.164.1914.13j6.19.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.4.458.0..0j0i131k1j0i10k1.0.3sk-7RVlO4Y) Am I missing something?

If I write percents separately (50 %), I get some results, but still only few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in academic writing, I'd usually write percentages as numbers, so 50%.

The 'of' is needed as well, so 50% of cases.

I don't think it really matters if one form of expression appears more than the other - people have different writing styles.

So to iterate: "the investigation can reveal the cause of 'X' in 50% of cases" is fine :)

Comment: Yes, 50% of sounds right to me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your search may also have been affected by a matter of style.

Depending on context, if *half* is not used, there are two other variations:

> 50%
>   fifty percent

According to *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 9.2:

> In nontechnical contexts, Chicago advises spelling out whole numbers from zero through one hundred and certain round multiples of those numbers . . .
>
> Thirty-two children from eleven families were packed into eight vintage Beetles.
>         Many people think that seventy is too young to retire.
>         The property is held on a ninety-nine-year lease.
>         According to a recent appraisal, my house is 103 years old.
>         The three new parking lots will provide space for 540 more cars.
>         The population of our village now stands at 5,893.

But in 9.3:

> Many publications, including those in scientific or journalistic contexts, follow the simple rule of spelling out only single-digit numbers and using numerals for all others.

So, you might want to try another search using *fifty percent* to see if that turns up a different result in your case.

---

But unless you are following a particular style guide, how you phrase the concept is simply a matter personal preference.